# Overriding static methods and polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding, static-methods

I read somewhere that **overriding** an `static` methods can **not** be considered **polymorphism**. Just *hiding the method*. What does it mean "*hide*"?

---

```
public class TesterClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassLetters.staticM();
        ClassA.staticM();

        ClassLetters Lettersobj = new ClassA();
        ClassA Aobj = new ClassA();


        Lettersobj.staticM();
        Aobj.staticM();
        ClassA aa = (ClassA) Lettersobj;
        aa.staticM();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Static Method Called in CLassLetters
Static Method Called in ClassA
Static Method Called in CLassLetters
Static Method Called in ClassA
Static Method Called in ClassA
```

---

`classA` inherits `ClassLetters` with same `static void classM`. Why it is not polymorphism?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Please include the full code, including the classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't override static members, because they are not inherited. They belong to the class itself, period.

If you create a subclass, and you create a (new) static method with the same name/parameters/... you don't override the original one, you re-define a new one.

So, the static method in your original class is not overridden, but hidden.